# Which json structure is better for my requirements?

Tags: javascript, json, amazon-dynamodb

I want to store links and text. The links can be of image, video or gifs. And i want to store them in order the user specifies.
Ex: img1, some text, video, img2 - This should be saved as json.

So far I have come up with 2 options:
 
**First:**

```
{
    "content": {
        "0": ["image", "image-link-here"],
        "1": ["text", "this is some text here"],
        "2": ["image", "2nd-image-link"],
        "3": ["video", "video-link"]
    }
}
```

**Second:** In this case, i can know if its image, video, gif or text by extension

```
{
    "content": ["https://somelink.com/pic.jpg", "this is a text", "https://somelink.com/pic2.png", "https://somelink.com/vid.mp4"]
}
```

I need to store these in DynamoDB. So which one would be good and correct keeping in mind that I expect DB to grow?
If both these approaches are bad, please suggest the good way to do it.

Comment: If an object consists of `{0: foo, 1: bar, 2: hi, 3: blah...}` then you may as well use an array because they emphasize that the data has some **order**, whereas objects have no *inherent* order to them.

Comment: The two examples are storing completely different things.

Comment: If in the second solution the text ends with ".jpg" what will you do? Do a regex on it to determine whether it is a link or not? This does not seem the  right way to go.

Comment: @trincot yes I realize now that using 2nd way and maybe having regex checks might me more expensive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to make arrays where each element has the same type/structure, as it will enable better searches.

The second solution is not specific enough. As a text could end with ".jpg", you'll need a more elaborate test to determine whether it is just text or not. The text might even look a lot like a URL...

The first is better, but it is not really helpful to have numerical keys. Instead you should combine per type, and use that type as the key name, and put the actual value(s) in an array value, like this:

```
{
    "content": {
        "images": ["image-link-here", "2nd-image-link"],
        "texts":  ["this is some text here"],
        "videos": ["video-link"]
    }
}
```

This structure should allow for most practical searches.

As you indicated in comments that you need to know the order of each item, then I would suggest to define content as an array, where the occurrence of elements in that array represent the order of them:

```
{
    "content": [
        { "image": "image-link-here" },
        { "text":  "this is some text here" },
        { "image": "2nd-image-link" },
        { "video": "video-link" }
    ]
}
```

Or, to make each of the objects have the same properties:

```
{
    "content": [
        { "type": "image", "value": "image-link-here" },
        { "type": "text",  "value": "this is some text here" },
        { "type": "image", "value": "2nd-image-link" },
        { "type": "video", "value": "video-link" }
    ]
}
```

The choice depends on which kind of queries you intend to do.

Comment: this is perfect if only i didnt require the order or elements. I thought of this too, but it is required that I need to know the order.

Comment: Added two alternatives for ordered lists.